# Parsing and validating numeric and DateTime input

Tags: c#, validation, parsing, datetime

So I am making a windows form with a separate class for student details and international student.  I need to validate that my Year mark for the student/international student is More than 0 and less than 100.

I would Also like to get the date of birth to show as dd/mm/yyyy but currently it shows as that plus the time.

I will include code below:

Date of birth first

```
student1.DateOfBirth = DateTime.Parse(txtDateofbirth.Text).Date;

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDateofbirth.Text))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a DoB");
}
```

Now for the Year Mark

```
try // Trying to do the thing in the curly braces
{
    student1.YearMark = Int32.Parse(txtYearMark.Text);
}
catch (Exception) // If it doesn't work skip the crash and print this
{
    MessageBox.Show("The Year mark must be a number and can't be empty");
}
```

Comment: It's not a full answer, but try using the TryParse methods on DateTime and then look at the various properties of the resulting DateTime instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use a DateTimePicker control for entering dates and a NumericUpDown control to enter the YearMark, instead of using TextBox.

The DateTimePicker control allows you to define the display format and restrict entry to a certain range.  If I remember correctly the Value property is of type DateTime so you don't have to parse a string.

The NumericUpDown control allows you to define a range of allowed values.  The Value property is of type Decimal, but you can safely cast that to an Int32.  That's a lot safer than parsing a String.

Answer (score 0):

There is an overload of the `ToString()` function for a date which will allow you to specify the exact format you want.

```
Date l_date = Date.Today();
l_date.ToString( "dd/MM/yyyy" );
```

For more information on available formats, visit the documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Parsing a `string` into an `int` can be done via the [`Int32.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) function, like so:

```
string x = "32";
int y = -1;
if ( !x.TryParse( x, out y ) ){
    // The parse failed
}
```

Then you can just test the value of your int to determine if it's in the desired range.

```
if ( y > 0 && y <= 100 ){
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to get the difference between the DateTime object and the current date, so you can create a TimeSpan object and get its 'Years' property.

   TimeSpan diff = new DateTime().subtract(dateOfBirth);

   if(diff.Years > 0 && diff.Years < 100)
   isValid = true;
2. To display DateTime objects in any required format, use the ToString() method with formatters.

   To solve your exact problem, try this:

   dateOfBirth.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"); //upper-case MM indicates month, while lower-case MM indicates minutes

Answer (score 0):

You could also make a simple method to test this here is an example as well

```
    IsDate(txtYearMark.Text);
    public static bool IsDate(string date)
    {
        DateTime Temp;
        return(DateTime.TryParse(date, out Temp)&&date.Length>=10)
    }
```